# Problemas com conexão com o banco do MS Access

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, microsoft-access

Pessoal desenvolvi uma aplicação web cujo banco de dados é do MS Access, pois bem, quando o usuário faz login eu envio os dados por ajax para a classe java para fazer a validação de login e senha, o problema é que quando o sistema vai conectar no banco minha classe de conexão da o seguinte erro "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess://banco_dados\softTech.accdb"
Até ai ok não está achando um driver, porém resolvi fazer um teste e criei um método "public static void main" na minha classe de conexão, e chamei o mesmo método de validação de login, a classe ficou da seguinte forma:

```
public static Connection conectar() {
    Connection conexao = null;
    try {
        conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://banco_dados\\softTech.accdb");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erro na conexão com o banco " + e.toString());
    }
    return conexao;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Funcionario f = new Funcionario();
        f.setLoginFuncionario("TESTE");
        f.setSenhaFuncionario("TESTE");
        String resultado = new FuncionarioDAO().validaLogin(f);
        System.out.println(resultado);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());

    }
}
```

Ao executar esta classe é que a coisa fica estranha, pois a conexão é feita normalmente, não sei o que pode estar havendo preciso de ajuda

O erro que dá é este:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess://src/banco_dados/softTech.accdb

mas como eu disse o driver foi inserido sim, e quando testo direto pela classe ele não dá erro nenhum.

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar **Class.forName()** :

```
  public static Connection conectar(){
     Connection conexao = null;
         try  {
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    conexao  = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://banco_dados\\softTech.accdb");
             }
             catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erro na conexão com o banco " + e.toString());
    }
    return conexao;
}
```

O problema aqui é de que as versões antigas do Java costumavam conectar o ODBC com o MS-Acess e o ODBC driver foi removido nas versões atuais do Java.

Comment: Olá Falion, dando uma olhada melhor na mensagem de erro percebi o seguinte trecho " net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: given file does not exist: banco_dados\softTech.accdb" ou seja pelo jeito a minha aplicação não esta encontrando meu arquivo access, isso quer dizer que ou eu estou colocando o arquivo no lugar errado dentro do projeto (se for isso onde seria o ideal colocar ?), ou então eu estou escrevendo o caminho de maneira errada (se for isso como deveria ser então ?), desde já obrigado !

Comment: Olá amigo,tente escrever o caminho inteiro até o .accdb,exemplo :  'jdbc:ucanaccess://c://folder/softTech.accdb' isto pode corrigir o seu erro,pois geralmente o Java consiste em dar erros deste tipo por não haver um caminho correto até o local.

Comment: Se te ajudei,coloque como +1 :)

Comment: por exemplo, usou o DSN para a conexão? 
sempre que há MS na jogada tem que usar mais de um caminho pra o arquivo
crie um alias para o arquivo e exporte junto na duplicação/instalação. resolve sempre ....